# I need to know why the (Int numeroCafe) doesn't work in my project

Tags: java, android, int

why can't I use `int` here?

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

        int numeroCafe = "5";
}
```

Comment: You are declaring an **int**... and assigning it a **string**. It will never work.

Comment: Assign a value without double quotes: ```int numeroCafe = 5;```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's pretty clear. `incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int`

Comment: You really need to learn the fundamentals of programming. No matter which language you choose.

Comment: Appreciate Rotwang  :)!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting a `String` into an `int` variable and this is not possible. In `JAVA` all the caracteres between "" are `Strings`. Only integer values are compatible with the `int` variable, change your code to this:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

        int numeroCafe = 5;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Luiz Fernando, um erro bobo de sintaxe.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer : You inserted a String literal instead of an integer value for your numeroCafe.

To make this work, you can write this : `int numeroCafe = 5;`

Java documentation can be found here on the data types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Thank you Daniel work perfect now and i learn what i did wrong

Comment: My pleasure, @PedroDuarte , learning Java basics beforehand could be really useful when developing android apps

Answer (score 1):

`"5"` represents String value. For integer use `5`.

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
        int numeroCafe = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please read about data types here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Don't worry about that!

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Because numeroCafe is a Int not a String.!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the variable with a data type **int** to a **String**, which it wouldn't allow you to do it. Instead assign it without the quotation marks.

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {

    int numeroCafe = 5;
```

}

You only use quotation marks when you are dealing with **String** data type.